# How does subsurface scattering RGB radius work?

Tags: materials, node-editor, subsurface-scattering

How does subsurface scattering RGB radius work? Right now, I have a light source and instead of RGB, it is showing cyan magenta and yellow. I don't know why this is happening and I have read documentation and watched video tutorials and nothing seems to have shown the problem or even properly explain how to use this tool.

Comment: Hello :). Magenta, Cyan and Yellow is a sign of way too high SSS radius. For realistic materials, keep the value around 0.01.